# Why does Windows 7's Virtual PC running Windows XP Professional have no "Shut down" button?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc

Why does Windows 7's Virtual PC running Windows XP Professional has no "Shut down" button -- if clicking on START, there is only "Log off".

To shut down, we need to press CTRL-ALT-END on the keyboard and then choose from a list of options...  I used XP Professional before on a real PC and it had a Shut Down option from the START menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the shutdown command in XP isn't really removed, just hidden.

use the Group Policy editor (Gpedit.msc) under the following location to configure Start menu features:

```
User Configuration \ Administrative Templates \ Start Menu and Taskbar
```

Policy:Disable and remove the Turn Off Computer button
Description:Removes the "Turn Off Computer" button from the Start Menu and
prevents shutting down Windows using the standard shutdown user interface.

or check this registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
```

Registry Value (DWORD):"NoClose" (1 = no Shutdown)

if you're not comfy with either option, you may create a shortcut to **shutdown.exe** and pin it to the start menu.

for possible switches, run this from a command prompt:

```
shutdown.exe /?
```

Answer (score 3):

On the top of the Virtual PC window, you have a Action menu. Select the Close item. Use this to shut down or hibernate the Virtual Machine.

[image]

You can change the default behavior in the settings for the XP Virtual Machine.

I suppose the "Shutdown" command in XP is removed by the Integration Features. I don't know what they did it, maybe it's better or faster VirtualPC controls itself the shutdown of the virtualized XP.

The [Windows Virtual PC blog](http://blogs.technet.com/windows_vpc/) has an article on [**how to shut down a virtual machine**](http://blogs.technet.com/windows_vpc/archive/2009/10/29/tip-how-do-i-shut-down-a-virtual-machine.aspx).